# VueJS - How to pass Axios response data from parent to child component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vuejs3

Using VueJS & Axios, how do I retrieve API data and pass it to multiple child components? I want to retrieve and pass this data through props so I will not have to access the API multiple times via the child components.

Currently, child component is returning 'undefined'.

**Parent**

```
<template>
    ...
    <my-child :foo="bar" />
    ...
    <my-other-child :foo="bar" />
    ...
</template>
<script>
    import axios from 'axios'
    ...
    mounted(){
        axios.get(...)
             .then(rsp => {this.bar = rsp.data.result})
             .catch(err => {console.warn(err)})
    }
    ...
</script>
```

**Child**

```
<script>
    props: ['foo'],
    mounted(){
        console.log(this.foo)
    }
</script>
```

Comment: requests are async so undefined is expected, the request finishes after your child components mounts. you can render child components after request completes

Comment: Leave them out of the DOM `<div v-if="bar"><my-child :foo="bar" /></div>`. Also, think about what bar *means* before the request completes.  Maybe null means that you're fetching, and the UI should represent that.  Maybe it's your current understanding of the result of an API, like `[]`

Comment: @danh Leaving out the DOM doesn't solve the issue. I need to data to be passed after retrieval.

Comment: It will be, @RyanPrentiss. See the snippet in my comment?  The completion of the api will change the value of bar, which will trigger (v-if) a rewrite of that div, which will mount that component

Comment: @RyanPrentiss use v-if="bar" or another variable to represent state of request. or you can use a watcher to see if data is being passed, if watcher triggered then data is passed correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`v-if=` (and its counterpart, `v-else`) control what's in the DOM conditionally based on the truth value of a js expression.  You can keep any node out of the dom (including your `my-child` components) by qualifying it with a v-if that evaluates to false.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    bar: null
  },
  mounted () {
    setTimeout(() => this.bar = 'foo', 2500);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <div v-if="bar">bar is {{bar}}</div>
    <div v-else>bar is not initialized</div>
  </div>
</div>
```